# Errors when linking Firebase C++ (analytics) library

Tags: android, c++, qt, firebase

I'm trying to build analytics support into a Qt (Android and iOS) application using the Firebase C++ libraries (2.0.0 / 2.1.0). When my app is being linked I get the following errors:

```
blaze-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8-bionic-armv7a-opt/genfiles/firebase/app/client/cpp/include/firebase/variant.h:533: error: undefined reference to 'firebase::Variant::assert_is_type(firebase::Variant::Type) const'
blaze-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8-bionic-armv7a-opt/genfiles/firebase/app/client/cpp/include/firebase/variant.h:543: error: undefined reference to 'firebase::Variant::assert_is_type(firebase::Variant::Type) const'
blaze-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8-bionic-armv7a-opt/genfiles/firebase/app/client/cpp/include/firebase/variant.h:553: error: undefined reference to 'firebase::Variant::assert_is_type(firebase::Variant::Type) const'
blaze-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8-bionic-armv7a-opt/genfiles/firebase/app/client/cpp/include/firebase/variant.h:567: error: undefined reference to 'firebase::Variant::assert_is_string() const'
firebase/analytics/client/cpp/src/analytics_android.cc:228: error: undefined reference to 'firebase::Variant::TypeName(firebase::Variant::Type)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing?

I'm including the following headers (following the examples from GitHub)

```
#include "firebase/analytics.h"
#include "firebase/analytics/event_names.h"
#include "firebase/analytics/parameter_names.h"
#include "firebase/analytics/user_property_names.h"
```

And linking against libapp.a and libanalytics.a in my pri file:

```
LIBS += -L$$FIREBASE_SDK_LIBS_PATH -lapp
LIBS += -L$$FIREBASE_SDK_LIBS_PATH -lanalytics
```

I have the AdMob example working in a similar setup - but I can't get the analytics to build...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the order of linking is important.

Link libanalytics.a before libapp.a and it works

```
LIBS += -L$$FIREBASE_SDK_LIBS_PATH -lanalytics
LIBS += -L$$FIREBASE_SDK_LIBS_PATH -lapp
```

(I was linking app first)